# Getting ""Uncaught TypeError: Could not add listener" When Using " chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When trying to use Chrome's WebNavigation.onCompleted to run background.js on a certain url I get the error
"Uncaught TypeError: Could not add listener".
For permissions in my manifest.json I have given the extension access to activetab and webrequest.

I have tried using other listeners like
        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener
and it worked perfectly. I am also using the latest version of chrome (v73).

background.js :

```
 chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(tab) {
    var eurl = tab.url.split("/skill/");
    if(eurl[0] === "https://www.duolingo.com") {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
            file: 'jquery-3.3.1.min.js'
        });
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
            file: 'duohelperinjector.js'
        });}

}, {url: [{urlMatches : '*://duolingo.com/skill/*'}]});
```

manifest.json :

```
{
    "name": "DuoHelper",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "A Chrome Extension That Helps With Duolingo",
    "homepage_url": "https://github.com/TechHax/DuoHelper",
    "background": {
      "scripts": [
        "background.js"
      ],
      "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "DuoHelper"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "webNavigation",
      "activeTab"
    ]
  }
```

The error I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Could not add listener

I would, with the extension working properly, like to have the chrome extension inject the javascript files on the active tab if its url is `*://duolingo.com/skill/*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted): `urlMatches` is a [RE2 regular expression](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt), not a [URL match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

#### Solution 1.

The correct RE2 expression would be `'https?://(www\\.)?duolingo\\.com/skill/.*'`

#### Solution 2.

A better approach is to do a plain string comparison of the host name and path because it's much faster than using regular expressions and the documentation explicitly advises to use regexps only when absolutely unavoidable:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(info => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(info.tabId, {file: 'jquery-3.3.1.min.js'});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(info.tabId, {file: 'duohelperinjector.js'});
}, {
  url: [{
    hostSuffix: '.duolingo.com',
    pathPrefix: '/skill/',
  }],
});
```

Note how hostSuffix utilizes an implicit dot added by the API before the first component to match any subdomain of duolingo.com. Also, the callback parameter is not a `tab`, but a [different object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#property-onCompleted-callback) with `tabId` inside.

#### Solution 3.

Use [declarativeContent API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) as shown in the documentation, but instead of ShowPageAction specify RequestContentScript, which despite the warning in the documentation actually works in the stable Chrome.